# Many to many property returns null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

I have two tables 
booksmandala_originals and blog_categories . 
Relation between these two is many to many and the pivot table name is bksm_original_categories
All other things completely works fine like data is being saved , updated but when I try to retrive data from blog_categories It gives me null even it has data like

In my

BooksmandalaOriginal.php

```
 public function blog_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin\BlogCategory', 'bksm_original_categories','bksm_originals_id','category_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In my BlogCategory.php

```
public function bksm_originals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin\BooksmandalaOriginal','bksm_original_categories','bksm_originals_id','category_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

My pivot migration looks like this .

```
 Schema::create('bksm_original_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->unsignedInteger('bksm_originals_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');

            $table->foreign('bksm_originals_id')->references('id')->on('booksmandala_originals')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        }
```

);

When I try to retrive the booksmandala originals from blog categories like this

```
$category = BlogCategory::where('id',$id)->first();
$category->bksm_originals; 
// It return empty array
```

But if I do like this .

```
$blog = BooksmandalaOriginal::find(1);
$blog->blog_categories;
// It return correct values
```

I have also tried doing this

```
$category = BlogCategory::find($id);
$blogs = $category->whereHas('bksm_originals', function($query) use ($category){
      $query->whereIn('id',$category->id);
})->get();
```

It gives me this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, int given
```

Comment: you have copied the same foreign keys on the bksm_originals() relationship. in your relationship definition. Thats why the first works and the second doesn't

Comment: What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship on blog category doesn't have the correct keys set.

Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the
> relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model
> names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this
> convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the
> belongsToMany method
>
> In addition to
> customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the
> column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments
> to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key
> name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while
> the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are
> joining to

So in your case:

```
public function bksm_originals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin\BooksmandalaOriginal','bksm_original_categories','category_id','bksm_originals_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Also to avoid these kinds of errors you should try to follow the Laravel naming conventions.